# What is the story Shiva spilling his semen in the case of Manasa's birth?

Tags: shiva

In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-was-goddess-manasa-born),it is discussed that Manasa was born when Shiva's semen  touched a statue carved by Kadru.Can someone provide me with the story of this?Does it have any scriptual basis?

Comment: It is mentioned in many Puranas that Rishi Kashyap and Kadru are the parents of Devi Manasa.-"The thirteen daughters who were married to Kashyapa were named Aditi, Diti, Danu, Arishta, Surasa, Surabhi, Vinata, Tamra, Krodhavasha, Ira, Kadru, Vishva and Muni,"

Comment: @Rickross I know but i am asking according to the bengali mangalkalvayas

Comment: @sv Erm how do i do that?