# Is Shiva father of Devi Manasa/Bishahari?

Tags: shiva, puranas

Manasa or Bishahari is a very well known Devi in eastern and western Indian states. She is a Devi of snakes and mother of snakes. My question is about her father. Somewhere it is said that Shiva is father of Devi Manasa. I don't know if it is true. And also some say that her father is sage Kashyapa and her mother is Kadru. So which version is correct?

Comment: Related or duplicate of [How was Goddess Manasa born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10783/3500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mother JaratKaaru is Daughter of Kashyapa and Disciple of Shiva.

> **Devi Puraana, 9th Book, Chapter 46**
>
> Manasaa is the **mind-born daughter of Maharsi Kasyapa**, hence she is named **"Manasa"**.
>   Her other name is **"Shaivi"** as She is the **disciple of Shiva.**
>   She is **capable to destroy the effects of poison** so She is called **"Visahari"**.

Here is how Supreme Mother Manasa Devi was born and became disciple of Shiva -
I have written in Short and full story is also provided.

> **Devi Puraana, Book 9, Chapter 48**
>
> 1. In old times people were terrified by snakes, so they went to refuge of Maharshi Kashyapa.
> 2. By command of Brahmaa He composed a Mantra.
> 3. **For making the Mantra , Maharshi Kashyapa thought  too intensely on Devi, the intensity of mind power was too high that a girl appeared from that, She is Manasaa Devi as She is born of mind(Manas) and fulfills desires of mind.**
> 4. **On being born She went to Kailasha and performed  devotion to Shiva and Supreme Lord Maheshvara taught her Supreme knowledge and SaamaVeda, and initiated Her in Mantra of Supreme Lord Krishna.**

Full story unabridged-

> **Devi Puraana, Book 9, Chapter 48**
>
> In olden days, men became greatly 
>   terrified on earth from snakes and took refuge of Kas’yapa, the supreme amongst the Munis.
>   The Maharsi Kas'yapa became very afraid. He then with Brahmâ, and by His command 
>   composed a mantra following the principal of the Vedas. **While composing this mantra, 
>   he intensely thought of the Devî, the Presiding Deity of that Mantra, through the power of his 
>   Tapasyâ and through the mental power, the Devî Manasâ appeared and was named so, as 
>   She was produced from the sheer influence of mind. On being born, the girl went to the 
>   abode of S’ankara in Kailâs’a and began to worship Him and chant hymns to Him with 
>   devotion. For one thousand Divine years, the daughter of Kas’yapa served Mahâdeva when 
>   He became pleased. He gave her the Great Knowledge, made Her recite the Sâma Veda 
>   and bestowed to her the eight-lettered Krisna mantra which is like the Kalpa Tree.**

Here is another mention of Manasa as Daughter of Kashyapa and Disciple of Shiva-

> **Devi Puraana, Book Nine, Chapter 1**
>
> **Manasâ Devî is the daughter of Kas’yapa. She is the dear disciple of S’ankara** and is therefore very learned in matters of S’âstras.

Comment: do you mean that actually sage Kashapya is father oof Manasa. But Shiva made her him daughter. Hmm.

Comment: @user9344763 I added another mention of Manasaa as Daughter of Kashyapa and Disciple of Shiva. From 1st chapter of 9 th book.

Comment: @user9344763 She is Daughter of Kashyapa born of His mind. As soon as she was born She went to Kailasha to serve Shiva for gaining divine knowledge. She served Him for 1 thousand year and then Shiva was pleased and made Her His disciple ang gave her knowledge and a Krishna Mantra.

Comment: Ok I understood.

Answer (score 1):

In purans daughter of sage kashyapa and kadru(mother of all nagas) but in Mangalkavyas lord shiva's daughter.

(more information and source):—https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manasa